# Adding 5th table to join

Tags: mysql, database

Maybe it's just too early but I can' figure out why I can't get the query of my fifth table to join with my current query statement.

Here is my current query

```
SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, count(xi.optionid) as cnt
FROM xcart_products xp
INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xp.productid = xc.productid AND xc.class = 'Color'
INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xc.classid = xco.classid
LEFT JOIN xcart_images_D xi ON xi.optionid = xco.optionid
GROUP BY xp.product, xco.optionid
ORDER by xp.product DESC
```

I am trying to add the following query which has a table set up very similar to xcart_images_D

```
JOIN xcart_images_T xiT ON xi.id = xiT.id
```

As of now, my results go from about 2,000 to 20 after I add the join.

Comment: Did you mean `JOIN xcart_images_T xiT ON xi.id = xiT.id` (You have one `xiT` too much before the `xi.id = xiT.id`)?

Comment: What's the problem? Are you seeing an error? Getting unexpected results? We don't know what's happening?

Comment: @JScoobyCed You were absolutely right about that, such an oversight on my part thank you.

SamDeHaan My apologies it was that the query wasn't work.  JScoobyCed was able to point out the syntax error.  After that it was the LEFT join BryceAtNetwork23 indicated.  Thank you for pointing out that I should have included a bit more information, you were absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this:

```
JOIN xcart_images_T xiT ON xi.id = xiT.id
```

You are making the JOIN of xcart_images_t dependent on your (xi) xcart_images_D table.  So if your xcart_images_D table doesn't match, then your xcart_images_T isn't going to return a match either.

Also by just specifying JOIN, you are implicitly indicating an INNER JOIN, which could also be part of your problem.  If having a match in xcart_images_T isn't a requirement, then it should be a LEFT JOIN.

The xcart_images_T  seems like it's similar to xcart_images_D, so try a LEFT JOIN and use the xco.optionid as a JOIN key:

```
LEFT JOIN xcart_images_T xiT ON xiT.id = xco.optionid
```

Also, if you're expecting to see any fields from xcart_images_T or xcart_images_D, you'll need to add those to your SELECT.  See if that helps.

Comment: You've got it Bryce, thank you for the assistance.  I ended up linking xiT.id with xp.productid but regardless thank you for not only pointing me the right direction but also for the explanation.

Comment: @Eric hey, no problem!  I'm just glad that you got it working.